# Combining hover mouseover with image-map

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouseover, imagemap

I am trying to create a hover mouseover effect where the onMouseOver item is a single image with three separate links.

I'm using a standard onMouseOver, onMouseOut effect and trying to combine it with an image map [like this one](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/).

The closest I can get is a MouseOver effect where the links show only when the image is in onMouseOut, and doesn't show the links when it's onMouseOver. In short, is there a way to combine these two effects so it shows the image map links on the onMouseOver image so that the two effects are working together?

[Here is an example](http://www.getwinston.com/new.html) showing the problem I'm trying to work through. To fully get the gist of the problem, try hovering your mouse over the image slowly from top to bottom.

Comment: it would be helpful if you included the code you've got so far

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do something like this is with CSS and the :hover selector.

```
image {
   background-image:url('image1.png');
}

image:hover {
   background-image:url('image2.png');
}
```

Of course, you'll need more styles here and appropriately selected elements to make this work the way you'd like.